# Destroy a return value from a function with multiple arguments using PyQt5 "Updated"

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

This is a code proposed by S.N all the thanks to him, using functional Programming.
It had a serious problem. If it gives runItem tuple some element for example ("222", 15), and this element didn't exist on the data dictionary, it's reference to the previous values duo to this method getbrutActifData() return. In fact, i want it to be a "0". Normally, the runItem for my program is a static asset contains all the keys that will suppose to be in a general data. But the dictionary will change depend on the data. This is the code if you have any suggestion, and thank you.
I update the code to inserting item_b_1 in cell (n, -1) with "0", if didn't exist in the dict.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

data = {'2111' :['Capital 1','1','1', '', '', '',  '1', '', '', '1','', '',  ''], 
        '23411':['Capital 2','2', '', '2','2','21','21','', '', '2','2','23','24'], 
        '23421':['Capital 3','3', '', '3','', '31','32','', '3','', '3','33','34'], 
        '3421' :['Capital 4','4', '', '4','4','41','42','', '4','4','4','43','44'], 
        '3422' :['Capital 5','5', '', '5','5','51','52','5','', '', '5','53','54'], 
        '3451' :['Capital 6','6', '', '', '6','61','62','6','', '', '6','63','64'], 
        '2230' :['Capital 7','7', '7','', '7','7', '7', '7','7','', '7','7', ''], 
        '3452' :['Capital 8','8', '', '', '8','81','82','', '8','8','8','83','84']}

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

    self.data = data
    self.item_n, self.item_b_1, self.item_b_2 = 0, 0, 0
    self.r = BlData(self.data, self.item_n, self.item_b_1, self.item_b_2)

    self.setuptUI()

def setuptUI(self):
    self.tableWidget_Bl = QTableWidget(55, 14, self)

    conLayout = QHBoxLayout()
    conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget_Bl)
    self.setLayout(conLayout)

    self.updateItems()

def updateItems(self):
    m = 5
    runItem = (("234", 10), ("222", 15), ("235", 15), ("342", 17), ("345", 19))          
    for k, n in runItem:                                      
        self.r.updateActifData( k, n )
        self.tableWidget_Bl.setItem(int(self.r.getrow()), m, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.r.getnData())))
        self.tableWidget_Bl.setItem(int(self.r.getrow()), m-1, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.r.getitem_1Data())))



class BalanceData():
    data = {}
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

class BlData(BalanceData):
    def __init__ (self, data, item_n, item_b_1, item_b_2):
        BalanceData.__init__(self, data)
def updateActifData(self, k, n):
    #the sum for one key 
    self.n = n
    self.item_n, self.item_b_1, self.item_b_2, item_1, item_2 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0                # +++
    item_3, item_4 = 0, 0                        
    v = 5
    for kd, vd in self.data.items():
        if kd[:len(k)] == k:
            s_1 = vd[v] 
            print("\n1 {:<10} -> {:10.2f}".format(kd, float(s_1) if s_1 else 0))
            item_1 = item_1 + (float(s_1) if s_1 else 0)
            #print(item)    
            s_2 = vd[v+1]  # the next range
            print("2 {:<10} -> {:10.2f}".format(kd, float(s_2) if s_2 else 0))
            item_2 = item_2 + (float(s_2) if s_2 else 0)

            item_b_1 = item_1 + item_2 

     for kd, vd in self.data.items():
         if kd[:len(k)] == k:
            s_1 = vd[v+6] 
            print("3 {:<10} -> {:10.2f}".format(kd, float(s_1) if s_1 else 0))
            item_3 = item_3 + (float(s_1) if s_1 else 0)
            #print(item)    
            s_2 = vd[v+7]  # the next range
            print("4 {:<10} -> {:10.2f}".format(kd, float(s_2) if s_2 else 0))
            item_4 = item_4 + (float(s_2) if s_2 else 0)

            item_b_2 = item_3 + item_4

    self.item_n = item_b_1 - item_b_2

    print("item_n= `{}`, item_b_1= `{}`, item_b_2= `{}`"
          "".format(self.item_n, self.item_b_1, self.item_b_2))

def getrow (self):
    print ("getrow:", self.n)
    return self.n

def getnData (self):
    return self.item_n

def getitem_1Data():
    return self.item_b_1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windows = Table()
    windows.setWindowTitle("QTableWidgetItem")
    windows.resize(1200, 800)
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

data = {'2111' :['Capital 1','1','1', '', '', '',  '1', '', '', '1','', '',  ''], 
        '23411':['Capital 2','2', '', '2','2','21','21','', '', '2','2','23','24'], 
        '23421':['Capital 3','3', '', '3','', '31','32','', '3','', '3','33','34'], 
        '3421' :['Capital 4','4', '', '4','4','41','42','', '4','4','4','43','44'], 
        '3422' :['Capital 5','5', '', '5','5','51','52','5','', '', '5','53','54'], 
        '3451' :['Capital 6','6', '', '', '6','61','62','6','', '', '6','63','64'], 
        '2230' :['Capital 7','7', '7','', '7','7', '7', '7','7','', '7','7', ''], 
        '3452' :['Capital 8','8', '', '', '8','81','82','', '8','8','8','83','84']}

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):   #*args, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = data
        self.item_n, self.item_b_1, self.item_b_2 = 0, 0, 0
        self.r = BlData(self.data, self.item_n, self.item_b_1, self.item_b_2)

        self.setuptUI()

    def setuptUI(self):
        self.tableWidget_Bl = QTableWidget(55, 14, self)

        conLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget_Bl)
        self.setLayout(conLayout)

        self.updateItems()

    def updateItems(self):
        m = 5

        runItem = (("234", 10), ("222", 15), ("235", 16), ("342", 17), ("345", 19)) 

        for k, n in runItem:                                      
            self.r.updateActifData( k, n )
            self.tableWidget_Bl.setItem(int(self.r.getrow()), m, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.r.getnData())))



class BalanceData():
    data = {}
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

class BlData(BalanceData):
    def __init__ (self, data, item_n, item_b_1, item_b_2):
        BalanceData.__init__(self, data)

    def updateActifData(self, k, n):
        #the sum for one key 
        self.n = n
        item_n, item_b_1, item_b_2, item_1, item_2 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        item_3, item_4 = 0, 0                        
        v = 5
        for kd, vd in self.data.items():
            if kd[:len(k)] == k:
                s_1 = vd[v] 
                print("\n1 {:<10} -> {:10.2f}".format(kd, float(s_1) if s_1 else 0))
                item_1 = item_1 + (float(s_1) if s_1 else 0)
                #print(item)    
                s_2 = vd[v+1]  # the next range
                print("2 {:<10} -> {:10.2f}".format(kd, float(s_2) if s_2 else 0))
                item_2 = item_2 + (float(s_2) if s_2 else 0)

#                self.item_b_1 = item_1 + item_2 
                item_b_1 = item_1 + item_2                              # +++

#        for kd, vd in self.data.items():
#            if kd[:len(k)] == k:
                s_1 = vd[v+6] 
                print("3 {:<10} -> {:10.2f}".format(kd, float(s_1) if s_1 else 0))
                item_3 = item_3 + (float(s_1) if s_1 else 0)
                #print(item)    
                s_2 = vd[v+7]  # the next range
                print("4 {:<10} -> {:10.2f}".format(kd, float(s_2) if s_2 else 0))
                item_4 = item_4 + (float(s_2) if s_2 else 0)

#                self.item_b_2 = item_3 + item_4
                item_b_2 = item_3 + item_4                                    # +++

#        self.item_n = self.item_b_1 - self.item_b_2
        self.item_n = item_b_1 - item_b_2                                     # +++

        print("item_n= `{}`, item_b_1= `{}`, item_b_2= `{}`"
              "".format(self.item_n, item_b_1, item_b_2))                     # +++
#              "".format(self.item_n, self.item_b_1, self.item_b_2))

    def getrow (self):
        print ("getrow:", self.n)
        return self.n

    def getnData (self):
        return self.item_n


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windows = Table(data)                             # data
    windows.setWindowTitle("QTableWidgetItem")
    windows.resize(1200, 800)
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: it's worked bro

Comment: How about Insert item_b_1 in a Cell (n, m-1)?

Comment: @AnassBelmaati  At the end of the loop `for k, n in runItem:`
insert the line `m -= 1`

Comment: If, i added m -=1 it will work only for item_n, i update the code

Comment: Thanks bro, i figure out the problem, i just put the assignment self.item_b_1 = 0 in    that function before get the value. Fail to learn